# finding the largest number in 2d array and its position in row and column

Tags: c++, visual-studio

With my code I can find the largest number in the matrix but I cant find the exact position (in rows and column)of the number. I'm a beginner so I don't know any fancy libraries and i prefer not to use them because i have not study them and its a 4X4 matrix
here id my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a[4][4], big1, n, m, i, j,loc1,loc2;
cout << "Enter no of rows and columns:";
cin >> m >> n;
cout << "Enter the array:\n";

for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}
cout << endl << "Entered Matrix: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        cout << " " << a[i][j];
        if (j == n - 1)
            cout << endl << endl;
    }


big1 = a[0][0];
loc1 = 0;
loc2 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
        if (a[i][j]>big1)
            big1 = a[i][j];
        loc1 = i;
        loc2 = j;
    }
}

cout << "\nLargest number:" << big1 << endl;
cout << "The position that had the largest number is " << loc1 <<" " << loc2 << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing some braces to update the location variables only for the maximum:

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
    if (a[i][j]>big1)
    {
        big1 = a[i][j];
        loc1 = i;
        loc2 = j;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is write with your code. Small things need to update add braces after if condition

Here it he updated code

```
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
        if (a[i][j]>big1){
            big1 = a[i][j];
            loc1 = i;
            loc2 = j;
       }
    }
}
```